# There is no row at position 0 and System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: sql, vb.net

Error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll and also showing a :There is no row at
>   position 0

```
 Dim mycn As New SqlConnection(connection)

    Dim DT As New DataTable

    mycn.Open()
    Dim Adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblUser where username ='" & txtRet.Text & "'", connection)
    Adapter.Fill(DT)

    txtUserID.Text = DT.Rows(0)("aid").ToString()
    txtFirstName.Text = DT.Rows(0)("fname").ToString()
    txtMiddleName.Text = DT.Rows(0)("mi").ToString()
    txtLastName.Text = DT.Rows(0)("lname").ToString()
    DateOfBirthDateTimePicker.Text = DT.Rows(0)("bday").ToString()
    txtAge.Text = DT.Rows(0)("age").ToString()
    cmbGender.Text = DT.Rows(0)("gender").ToString()
    txtContactNo.Text = DT.Rows(0)("contactno").ToString()
    txtEmail.Text = DT.Rows(0)("email").ToString()
    txtAddress.Text = DT.Rows(0)("address").ToString()
    txtUsernamePS.Text = DT.Rows(0)("username").ToString()
    txtPasswordPS.Text = DT.Rows(0)("password").ToString()
    rtbSQuestions.Text = DT.Rows(0)("squestion").ToString()
    rtbAnswer.Text = DT.Rows(0)("answer").ToString()

    Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = _
            DT.Rows(0)("userimage")
    Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
    UserPictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)


    mycn.Close()
```

Comment: DT.Rows(0) is empty, you should add something to DT first. Alternatively your question could be: how to add rows from some SQL table to a variable...

Comment: I agree with Hansa, this will be better served for you if you gave some context and framed it more as a clear question. :)

Comment: No descriptive title, no explanation and an error which 1) is easy to fix since the exception is absolute clear about what goes wrong and 2) has been answered a trillion times on SO (DataAdapter, SQL Parameter, SQL Injection, ...)

Comment: Check `DT.Rows.Count > 0` before using `DT`

Comment: thank you so much, i already got it. thank a lot :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that no rows were returned and since you're trying to get the first row (...DT.Rows(0)...) it is throwing the error.

My first suggestion would be to wrap your code in Using statements for all of the objects that implement iDisposable. My second suggestion would be to utilize a parameterized query. My last suggestion would be to check if Rows(0) exists before trying to access it.

Here is a quick example:

```
    'Declare the connection object
    Dim con As SqlConnection

    'Wrap code in Try/Catch
    Try
        'Set the connection object to a new instance
        con = New SqlConnection(connection)

        'Create a new instance of the command object
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [tblUser] WHERE [username]=@username;", con)
            'Parameterize the query
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtRet.Text)

            'Open the connection
            con.Open()

            'Declare a new adapter to fill the data table
            Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            adapter.Fill(DT)

            'Close the connection
            con.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Display the error
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        'Check if the connection object was initialized
        If con IsNot Nothing Then
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                'Close the connection if it was left open(exception thrown)
                con.Close()
            End If

            'Dispose of the connection object
            con.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try

    If DT.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtUserID.Text = DT.Rows(0)("aid").ToString()
        txtFirstName.Text = DT.Rows(0)("fname").ToString()
        txtMiddleName.Text = DT.Rows(0)("mi").ToString()
        txtLastName.Text = DT.Rows(0)("lname").ToString()
        DateOfBirthDateTimePicker.Text = DT.Rows(0)("bday").ToString()
        txtAge.Text = DT.Rows(0)("age").ToString()
        cmbGender.Text = DT.Rows(0)("gender").ToString()
        txtContactNo.Text = DT.Rows(0)("contactno").ToString()
        txtEmail.Text = DT.Rows(0)("email").ToString()
        txtAddress.Text = DT.Rows(0)("address").ToString()
        txtUsernamePS.Text = DT.Rows(0)("username").ToString()
        txtPasswordPS.Text = DT.Rows(0)("password").ToString()
        rtbSQuestions.Text = DT.Rows(0)("squestion").ToString()
        rtbAnswer.Text = DT.Rows(0)("answer").ToString()
    End If
```